# Sudden problem with Apache log4j Appender when trying to launch SBT

Tags: scala, sbt, log4j, appender

I was executing a scala program with SBT and needed to stop the execution, so I hit Ctrl+c to end execution, which also ends the execution of SBT. I've done this a thousand times, but this time SBT wouldn't restart, and gives me this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/core/Appender
    at sbt.StandardMain$.initialGlobalLogging(Main.scala:114)
    at sbt.StandardMain$.initialState(Main.scala:136)
    at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:70)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.$anonfun$run$1(Launch.scala:149)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:176)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:149)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.$anonfun$apply$1(Launch.scala:44)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:159)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:44)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:21)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:78)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.run(Boot.scala:73)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:21)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Appender
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 14 more
[error] [launcher] error during sbt launcher: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/core/Appender
```

I tried installing a new version of SBT but that didn't work, and I get the same error.
I'm at a complete loss as to how to fix this problem.  I really don't even know what the problem is.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to get things working but I won't guarantee this would be a fix for everyone.  Deleting my .sbt folder and restarting sbt worked. It created a new .sbt folder and everything is working correctly now.  I only use sbt for compiling scala code so there isn't much that depends on sbt.  Definitely back up your old .sbt folder if you're going to try this route.